# Counting the pips on dice using OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

I am doing a dice value recognition hobby project that I want to run on a Raspberry Pi. For now, I am just learning OpenCV as that seems like the hardest thing for me. I have gotten this far, where I have dilated, eroded and canny filtered out the dice. This has given me a hierarchy of contours. The image shows the bounding rectangles for the parent contours:

[image]

My question is: how would I proceed to count the pips? Is it better to do some template matching for face values, or should I mathematically test if a pip is in a valid position within the bounding box?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There could be multiple ways to do it:

1. Use hole filling and then morphological operator to filter circles.
2. Simpler approach would be using white pixel density (% of white pixels). Five dot would have higher white pixel density.
3. Use image moments (mathematical property which represents shape and structure of image) to train the neural network for different kinds of dice faces.

Reference:
Morphology
http://blogs.mathworks.com/pick/2008/05/23/detecting-circles-in-an-image/

Answer (score 1):

As Sivam Kalra Said, there are many valid approaches.

I would go with template matching, as it should be robust and relatively easy to implement.

- using your green regions in the canny image, copy each found die face from the original grayscale image into a smaller search image. The search image should be slightly larger than a die face, and larger than your 6 pattern images.
- optionally normalize the search image
- use [cvMatchTemplate](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/template_matching/template_matching.html) with each of the 6 possible dice patterns (I recommend the CV_TM_SQDIFF_NORMED algorithm, but test which works best)
- find and store the global minimum in the result image for each of the 6 matches
- rotate the search image in ~2° steps from 0° to 90°, and repeat the template match for each step

the dice pattern with the lowest minimum over all steps is the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

contour hierechy could be a good and very easy option, but you need a perpendicular vision.

so you can do it with contours but fitting circles with som threshold

(sorry about my apalling english)